# Network error log on spark docker(bitnami/spark) cluster

Tags: apache-spark, bitnami

- Server 1 : Master, Slave Node
- Server 2 : Slave Node
- Server 3 : Slave Node

When I execute the *pi.py* example to master node, many jobs were finished with Exit code 1.

Same goes for the log message in *workernode*, like below.

However, I don't know the exact reason... Could you give me some advise???

```
20/03/12 13:21:54 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 7571@803acbaf5fbf
20/03/12 13:21:54 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
20/03/12 13:21:54 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
20/03/12 13:21:54 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
20/03/12 13:21:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/03/12 13:21:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark,root
20/03/12 13:21:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark,root
20/03/12 13:21:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
20/03/12 13:21:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
20/03/12 13:21:55 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark, root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark, root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1713)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to 67f75f899bac:43487
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 67f75f899bac
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:143)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:143)
        at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32)
        at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:202)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:48)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:182)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:168)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:604)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:985)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:505)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:416)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:475)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:518)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more
```

Could you give me some advise???

Answer (score 1):

This means that the worker nodes are not able to reach the master node. Because you are using spark inside docker, docker containers both workers and Master should be able to communicate. Update /etc/hosts for all nodes with correct Ip addresses.

You can also update the docker host /etc/hosts and attach it as a volume with `-v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts:rw` inside the container.

Add `--network host` to your run command to allow port mapping with the docker host. Change the hostname of the containers.

Add -e SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://YOUR_HOST:7077 to your run command

Answer (score 0):

I founded this [thread](https://mapr.com/community/s/question/0D50L00006j9ne6SAA/problem-with-spark-through-mapr-client) with a similar problem.
  Could you check your acls ?